# RabbitMQ pause a queue

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I am using a RabbitMQ Server (v3.8.9) with Java clients.
Use case is:
Our Backend creates messages for different clients. We send them out to their respective Endpoints.

- 1 Producer -> Outbound Queue -> 1 Consumer
- The producer creates messages for n clients
- Which the consumer should send out to the clients' endpoints
- Messages must be kept in the correct order regarding each client

Works fine, unless all clients are up and running. Problem: If one client becomes unavailable, we need to have a bulletproof retry mechanism for that.
Say:

- Wait 1 Minute and try again
- All following messages must NOT be delivered before the first failed one and kept in the correct order
- If a retry works, then ALL other messages should be send to the client immediately

As you can see, it is not a solution to just "supsend" the consumer, because it should still deliver msg to the other (alive) clients. Due to application limitations and a dynamic number of clients, we cannot spawn one consumer per client queue.
My best approach right now is to dynamically create one queue per client, which are then routed to a single outbound queue. If one msg to one client cannot be delivered by the consumer, I would like to "pause" the clients queue for x minutes. An API call like "queue_pause('client_q1', '5 Minutes')" would help. But even then I have to deal with the other, already routed messages to that particular client and keep them in the correct order...
Any better ideas?

Comment: You say your best approach right now is "to dynamically create one queue per client, which are then routed to a single outbound queue"; this doesn't actually make any sense in RabbitMQ terminology. A message is published to an exchange, and the broker routes it to zero or more queues; once it's in a queue, it sits there until something consumes it. (The only exception I can think of is setting a TTL and a Dead Letter Exchange, so that messages decay out of a queue back to a new exchange, and from there potentially to a new queue; but I don't see how that would be useful or relevant here.)

Comment: ... Right... It makes sense, when you have just one possible Consumer due to application limitation... The idea behind was a workaround: when detecting a client is unavailable i wanted to unbind the client specific queue from the outbound queue, so msg stack there, until i add the bindung on the Exchange again... But it had too many flaws. I just wanted to know, if you could pause a queue. If I had control over all parts of the application, I knew exactly how to model it...

Comment: The phrase "unbind the client specific queue from the outbound queue" still makes no sense to me. If both really are queues, then there must be something consuming from one and publishing to the other, so you could indeed pause it; but you make it sound like messages are flowing straight from one queue to another, which AFAIK is impossible in RabbitMQ's model.

Comment: true, i thought it was possible to connect 2 queues with an exchange...

Answer (score 1):

I think the key here is that a single consumer script can consume from multiple queues. So if I'm understanding correctly, you could model this as:

- Each client has its own queue. These could be created by the consumer script when it starts up, or by a back-end process when a new client is created.
- The consumer script subscribes to each queue separately
- When a message is received, the consumer tries to send it immediately to the client; if it succeeds, it is [manually acknowledged](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) with `basic.ack`, and the consumer is ready to send the next message *to that client*.
- When a message cannot be delivered to the client, it is requeued (`basic.nack` or `basic.reject` with `requeue=1`), retaining its position in the client's queue.
- The consumer then needs to pause consuming from that particular queue. Depending on how its written, that could be as simple as a `sleep` in that particular thread, but if that's not practical, you can effectively "pause" the *subscription* to the queue:

  - Cancel the subscription to that queue, leaving other subscriptions in tact
  - Store the queue name and the retry time in an appropriate variable
  - If the consumer script is implemented with an event/polling loop, check the list of "paused" subscriptions each time around that loop; if the retry time has been reached, re-subscribe.
  - Alternatively, if the library / framework supports it, register a delayed event that will fire at the appropriate time and re-subscribe the queue. The exact mechanics of this depend on the technologies you're using.
- All the other subscriptions will continue, so messages to other clients will be delivered. The queue with no subscribers will retain the messages for the offline client in order until the consumer script starts consuming them again.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction! You are perfectly right, that would be a solution in a normal environment +1 for that. Unfortunately your first point is near to impossible. The consumer should never wait actively (thread-number and -time are expensive here). Etc. So additional restriction: Queue-to-consumer subscriptions are STATIC in my scenario. There must be a different way.

Comment: @Sauer I gave sleep as one possibility, but my main suggestion was for the consumer script to unsubscribe and re-subscribe. I've expanded that section of the answer, is that clearer now?

Comment: as i said: one consumer per client-queue is not an option. So i cannot pause the consumer

Comment: @Sauer Your requirements seem to be contradictory: either you have a single queue, with the messages from all clients combined (in which case there's nothing to pause); or you have multiple queues, and something reading from each of those queues (in which case you can pause that thing). That doesn't have to mean separate processes or threads - in some connection libraries, a "subscription" is just a mapping of "when a message comes in on this queue, run this callback", and the code executes asynchronously but entirely on one thread.

Comment: I appreciate your help and again: You are right with what you say! My issue is, that I do not have control over my consumer. It is wrapped inside something I cannot change. It just takes a queue and listens to that static queue and nothing else. I need to change that in the future. For now I solved my issue with basic_gets with HTTP and reading from dynamic client queues (as you'd usually do it with normal consumers)...